# How can I stop the accordion(collapsible) from closing when checkboxes are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I want users to be able to check the checkbox without closing the accordion body.

I have tried to stop propagation however, I was unable to get this to work.

I'm using the [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/collapsible.html) framework however, it doesn't provide any options to override this behavior.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.collapsible-header {
  position: relative;
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First
      <span class="test">
        <input id="demo-1" name="demo-1" type="checkbox">
        <label for="demo-1"></label>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second
      <span class="test">
        <input id="demo-2" name="demo-2" type="checkbox">
        <label for="demo-2"></label>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third
      <span class="test">
        <input id="demo-3" name="demo-3" type="checkbox">
        <label for="demo-3"></label>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe you mean that you do not want a tab to be collapsed when the checkbox of **another** tab is clicked on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is simple: simply stop the click event from propagating from the input group (using `event.stopPropagation`), which has the class of `test` in your example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.collapsible .test').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.collapsible-header {
  position: relative;
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First
      <span class="test">
        <input id="demo-1" name="demo-1" type="checkbox">
        <label for="demo-1"></label>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second
      <span class="test">
        <input id="demo-2" name="demo-2" type="checkbox">
        <label for="demo-2"></label>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third
      <span class="test">
        <input id="demo-3" name="demo-3" type="checkbox">
        <label for="demo-3"></label>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```